# Shell Extension - Virtual File Creation

Tags: shell-extensions, ramdisk

I want to create a file that only resides in memory...  In looking through some documentation I saw a recommendation to use a shell extension as a virtual file.  Im not sure that is a workable solution but I would like to know

1. Is it a good approach (or should I be using a ramdisk instead)
2. Where is a good place to start to read up on it

Note:  This is on the Windows platform

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand, you want your program to create a "file", which resides only in memory and that you can pass on to another external program (say, Microsoft Word).

AFAIK this is not possible, short of a ramdrive. I'd suggest using a temporary folder. You will however have to come up with a strategy for deleting the file when it's not needed anymore.

**Added:** On second though, you might want to check out [Reparse points](http://msdn.microsoft.com/lv-lv/library/aa365503(en-us,VS.85).aspx). I'm not familiar with them myself, and they will only work for NTFS formatted disks, but perhaps they can provide you with what you want. It will be a lot of coding though.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say on which plateform you are but I'm guessing Windows.  Is mmap() available?  If not, I think [BerkeleyDB](http://www.oracle.com/database/berkeley-db/index.html) has been ported to Windows so you should be able to use that.  Win32 API may have something akin to mmap() but I don't know it.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, mmap'ing a file won't load it into memory, it'll just give you a virtual memory pointer from where you can access the file. It'll only get into memory if you read from it (and into swap if the OS needs the memory)

Comment: You're right about mmap(3) but that may be enough for the OP.  Anyway, BDB ought to work too.

Comment: Actually yes it is windows but the file in question is a document (word, adobe, etc).... I'm not sure how an embedded db is going to help in that regard.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a file that resides only in memory, use a named pipe or something, though I question your scenario - can you go up a level and describe what you want to do?

Comment: I want to open a word document but have the word document only in memory (not on disk, nor in a temp file)